# Pass through the file system from a given directory and print all subfolders and file names (Python)

Tags: python

I need to write a program that passes through the file system from a given directory and prints all subfolders and files names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

def walklevel(some_dir, level):
    some_dir = some_dir.rstrip(os.path.sep)
    num_sep = some_dir.count(os.path.sep)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(some_dir):
        yield root, dirs, files
        num_sep_this = root.count(os.path.sep)
        if num_sep + level <= num_sep_this:
            del dirs[:]        

for root,dirs,files in walklevel('.',3):
    for dir in dirs:
        tabs='\t'*root.count(os.path.sep)
        print tabs,dir
```

Answer (score 5):

[`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) is your friend.

Comment: In link that you gave (Python docs) there are no examples. Could you please help me and exlain the code?

Comment: @Bob The documentation actually points directly to an example!

Comment: @Bob: No, there are two examples there.

Answer (score 0):

This Python example should help you solve your problem.

```
for ROOT,DIR,FILES in os.walk("/mypath"):
    for file in FILES:
       print file
    print DIR 
    rc = performOtherPythonTasks()
```